# how to have make targets for separate debug and release build directories?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am looking for suggestions to properly handle separate debug and release build subdirectories, in a recursive makefile system that uses the $(SUBDIRS) target as documented in the gnumake manual to apply make targets to (source code) subdirectories.

Specifically, I'm interested in possible strategies to implement targets like 'all', 'clean', 'realclean' etc. that either assume one of the trees or should work on both trees are causing a problem.

Our current makefiles use a COMPILETYPE variable that gets set to Debug (default) or Release (the 'release' target), which properly does the builds, but cleaning up and make all only work on the default Debug tree. Passing down the COMPILETYPE variable gets clumsy, because whether and how to do this depends on the value of the actual target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to have specific targets in the subdirectories for each build type.  So if you do a "make all" at the top level, it looks at COMPILETYPE and invokes "make all-debug" or "make all-release" as appropriate.

Alternatively, you could set a COMPILETYPE environment variable at the top level, and have each sub-Makefile deal with it.

The real solution is to not do a recursive make, but to include makefiles in subdirectories in the top level file.  This will let you easily build in a different directory than the source lives in, so you can have *build_debug* and *build_release* directories.  It also allows parallel make to work (make -j). See [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are disciplined in your Makefiles about the use of your $(COMPILETYPE) variable to reference the appropriate build directory in all your rules, from rules that generate object files, to rules for clean/dist/etc, you should be fine.

In one project I've worked on, we had a $(BUILD) variable that was set to (the equivalent of) build-(COMPILETYPE) which made rules a little easier since all the rules could just refer to $(BUILD), e.g., clean would rm -rf $(BUILD).

As long as you are using $(MAKE) to invoke sub-makes (and using GNU make), you can automatically exporting the COMPILETYPE variable to all sub-makes without doing anything special. For more information, see the [relevant section of the GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion).

Some other options:

- Force a re-build when compiler flags change, by adding a dependency for all objects on a meta-file that tracks the last used set of compiler flags.  See, for example, how [Git manages object files](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Makefile;h=b040a96e50a30c5413f109d4e49d9c538625918f;hb=HEAD).
- If you are using autoconf/automake, you can easily use a separate build out-of-place build directory for your different build types.  e.g., `cd /scratch/build/$COMPILETYPE && $srcdir/configure --mode=$COMPILETYPE && make` which would take the build-type out of the Makefiles and into configure (where you'd have to add some support for specifying your desired build flags based on the value of `--mode` in your `configure.ac`)

If you give some more concrete examples of your actual rules, maybe you will get some more concrete suggestions.